# De-select/ highlight logic for listBox WinForm C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, listbox

I'm struggling to form the logic to de-select an item when either clicking the same item again or simply clicking off the listBox (if thats possible).

Currently i've set a variable `prevSelectedIndex = -2` and then in the `selectedIndexChanged()` method for the listBox -> i check if the `list.SelectedIndex == prevSelectedIndex`
if thats true then i call the `ClearSelected()` method of list.

If false, i set `prevSelectedIndex = SelectedIndex` and pass the `selectedIndex` through to a function so that i can pre-set some input fields with the data in the item selected. However, it fails to ever remove it as i think the `selectedIndexChanged()` method of listbox obviously is only called when it does change rather than staying the same (for trying to de-select when clicking same item again).

Moreover, when i click within/outside list box but not on an item, i tried checking to see if output would maybe change to something other than an index such as -1 yet this does not occur.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ ... In a typical Winforms application, it's unlikely that you need the behavior you're describing.

Comment: You may try to define "clicking off the listBox" better. There are other methods using a ui then the mouse. Do you maybe mean the listbox looses focus?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It would just be my preference for this to occur -> also better UX due to not having the input fields always filled, just if a user has selected an item. Thanks for the response

Comment: @Ralf That sounds of interest, could possibly be enough for me to be happy with how it works. Thanks will just have a look at listBox's methods now for that

Comment: Look at either the Leave or LostFocus events.

Comment: May I know if the answer can solve your issue? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Comment: Hi, just looked at the answer and yes that would work fine, the focus method i tried however changed some other parts that meant it wasn’t the best for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged` is not the right event to handle if you need to toggle the selection state of an item by mouse inputs. You need to handle the mouse events.

For example, you can handle the `MouseClick` event to call the [`IndexFromPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.indexfrompoint?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.IndexFromPoint);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) method which returns the index of an item if you click over it or `-1` if you click on the client area. Then, you can compare that index with a class field that stores the last selected index either by mouse or keyboard arrows and unselect the item if you get equal numbers.

Put it all together along with the other requirement

```cs
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    private int toggleIndex = -1;

    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void yourListBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var s = sender as ListBox;
            var i = s.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);

            if (i >= 0)
            {
                if (i == toggleIndex)
                {
                    s.SetSelected(i, false);
                    // or
                    // s.ClearSelected();
                    i = -1;
                }                
            }
            else
            {
                s.ClearSelected();
            }

            toggleIndex = i;
        }
    }

    private void yourListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toggleIndex = yourListBox.SelectedIndex;
    }

    private void yourListBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toggleIndex = -1;
        yourListBox.ClearSelected();
    }
}
```